# Faking user agent for mobile application

Tags: java-me, wap, midp-2.0

I'm building a mobile application that displays the source of a WAP site. but I am not able to get the html source of my operator WAP site http://divein.tatadocomo.com. I doubt its the user agent that is missing. So can I fake a mobile application to act as WAP browser to extract the source contents. The application is build on MIDP Java 2.0

Or is it something else other that user-agent that is causing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Nice question, yes there are other factors that an Operator in this case might take into account.

1. They can determine if you are own their network (i.e. originating IP which you can't change)
2. They could perhaps be looking at other HTTP headers other than *User-Agent*.  One of them is: *Accept* header (this tells the server what kind of pages it can accept, e.g. html, wml etc)

Have a look at all the http headers in your browser (using Chrome for example) and see which one's you can play with.
Secondly, hit a site that echo's back all your headers from a mobile device, then emulate all those headers on your pc and see if it works.  If it doesn't, then it's most probably your IP.

Comment: IP is okay. Cause its the same Docomo sim that I'm using. and the page is loading in WAP browser but not in the mobile app.